# Identity column in SQL Server exposes strange behaviour

Tags: c#, database, sql-server-2008, dataset, identity

I have an `identity` (auto increment integer) column in my data table in a SQL Server database.

When I start my program and add new record to this table identity column always equals -1. For the next record it becomes -2 and so on. I add new record this way:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ycd1034.aspx

However when I restart my program all identity values are reordered (become 1, 2, ...).

Any ideas why this happens? It would be no issue if i could delete these records without restarting. I use SQL Server 2008.

Also is there any way to specify `MAX` size for column data type through GUI interface (when adding table in visual studio 2012 server explorer) ?

Answer (score 2):

Why they are negative I don't know. However, when you reload the application those records already exist in the database and have id's that were assigned when they were committed to the database; that's why they have real values on restart.

But, you don't need to delete the records from the `DataTable`, you just need to refresh that row after committing it to the database. There are a number of ways to do this, and would depend significantly on exactly how you're accessing your data now, but you can do things like tack on the `SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()` command with the `INSERT` command and then use `ExecuteScalar` to commit the row, like this:

```
var insertCmd = "INSERT INTO tbl (fld1, fld2) VALUES (@fld1, @fld2); SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()";

using (var c = new SqlConnection(connString))
using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(insertCmd, c))
{
    cmd.AddParameterWithValue("@fld1", fld1Value);
    cmd.AddParameterWithValue("@fld2", fld2Value);

    var result = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
    int id;
    if (int.TryParse(result, out id))
    {
        // update the DataTable row here
        dataTable.Rows[index]["id_column"] = id;
        dataTable.AcceptChanges();
    }
}
```

You could even choose to reload the entire `DataTable` after performing the update.

Comment: This is very interesting.  Do you have a reference to the documentation on this?

Comment: @GordonLinoff: I don't because the documentation states that it starts at 1 and not -1; but -1 is how it's always worked. Well, not that I care anymore because I don't use data tables anymore. But I'm going to test it locally.

Comment: I ask because it seems like strange behavior.  As far as I know, nothing prevents inserting a negative seed value for the identity, and then things might get confusing.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: I can't recreate it locally so I'm going to edit my answer to indicate that I don't know why it's `-1`; it's possible that my experience (years ago) was that **we** were starting the seed at `-1` in our application. My apologies.

Comment: It is strange, i commit changes with BindingSource.EndEdit and TableAdapter.Update, but it yet doesn't save row to database.

Comment: @igntec: so it's **not** committing the row to the database? You said in your question when you reload the app the rows are there. That would purport that the rows **are** being committed to the database.